# How to perform lookup in Angular using Subscribe Observable

Tags: javascript, angular

First of all, I am a greenhorn in Angular so my approach may not be correct. Please let me know if there is a better solution and how to do it.

My objective is to display a list of records in the table format (row-by-row).  I managed to retrieve the list of record from the database and the list only contains Foreign Keys ID which forces me to perform a lookup in order to display the name as the UI render.  I am not sure how to accomplish this using Subscribe.  I am not even sure if this is the correct approach or I must break my logic into multiple actions.

I need help with the syntax for looking up the values against another datasource to display on the table using Angular Subscribe technique.  I include the output of my table, the debug session to show the output of my collection and the lookup table values.

Form elements:

```html
 this.recoverySolutionForm = this.fb.group({
      resourceDependencyId: [''],
      rtoId: [''],
      rtcId: { value: '', disabled: true },
      rtGapId: [''],
      rtActionId: [''],
      strategyId: [''],
      startImplementationId: [''],
      rpoId: [''],
      rpcId: { value: '', disabled: true },
      rpGapId: [''],
      rpActionId: [''],
      comment: ['']
    });

  public getRecoverySolutions(deptId: string, bpId: string): void
  {

this.recoverySolutions = null;

if (bpId)
{
  console.log(`Selected Business Process Id: ${this._selectedBusinessProcessId}`);

  // call service to retrieve recovery solutions from the database
  this.recoveryySolutionService.getRecoverySolutions(deptId, bpId)
    .subscribe(response =>
    {
      // response result
      this.recoverySolutions = response;

      // perform look up to map IDs into values
    },
      error => this.handleError(error));

}
  }
```

```html
// Data source for lookup tables

public getResourceDependencies(): void
  {
    this.service.getResourceDependencies()
      .subscribe(response =>
      {
        this.resourceDependencies = response;
      },
        error => this.handleError(error),
        () => console.log('Resource dependencies request completed')
      );
  }

  public getRecoveryTimePeriods(): void
  {
    this.service.getRecoveryTimePeriods()
      .subscribe(response =>
      {
        this.recoveryTimePeriod = response;
      },
        error => this.handleError(error),
        () => console.log('Recovery time periods request completed ')
      );
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This other data source that you need to lookup against, do you have that data available on the client? Or do you need to do an additional Http request to get it?

Comment: @snorreDan, the lookup values are already available in the client.  I don't know the correct syntax in Angular to chain the result together.  I can do individual lookup.

Comment: Here is the code for getting the lookup tables.
// Data source for lookup tables

public getResourceDependencies(): void
  {
    this.service.getResourceDependencies()
      .subscribe(response =>
      {
        this.resourceDependencies = response;
      },
        error => this.handleError(error),
        () => console.log('Resource dependencies request completed')
      );
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer.

I looked up for a cleaner way to map an Id to a string (e.g. X.id to X.name).  The RxJS operator provides the "combineLatest".  I found the answer through the PluralSight video by Deborah Kurata ("RxJS in Angular: Reactive Development").  Sample code from the video is below:

```js
    // Combine products with categories
  // Map to the revised shape.
  productsWithCategory$ = combineLatest([
    this.products$,
    this.productCategoryService.productCategories$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([products, categories]) =>
      products.map(product => ({
        ...product,
        price: product.price * 1.5,
        category: categories.find(c => product.categoryId === c.id).name,
        searchKey: [product.productName]
      }) as Product)
    ),
    shareReplay(1)
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work using brute force.  I am not Angular smart so my solution may not be optimal.  If you see a smarter way of accomplishing this, I am willingly to learn.

```html
      this.recoveryySolutionService.getRecoverySolutions(deptId, bpId)
        .subscribe(response =>
        {

          // result of the response
          const result = response;

          // perform look up
          result.map(x =>
          {
            x.resourceDependencyId = this.findResourceDependenciesById(x.resourceDependencyId);
            x.rtoId = this.findRecoveryTimePeriodById(x.rtoId);
            // remove the rest of look up for brevity
          });

          // set the result to the data source
          this.recoverySolutions = result;

        });
```

Comment: There is a cleaner way.  You need to keep the ids in an object with resourceDependencyId as the key. Once you get the resourceDependencyId from HTTP response, bam! just pull up value for that id. no bruteforce needed.